# Why is Unity Canvas Image always rendering over my gameObjects even though it is definitely behind them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas, position

[image: Canvas image always over gameObjects]

In my 2d Unity project, I have a Canvas with an Image that I want for a Background.

I have 2 gameObjects in front of this background. But no matter how much fiddling I do with Pos Z, Sorting Layers, or hierarchy sorting, the image is always in front of the objects.

Gif above shows in 3d mode that even though the image is clearly behind these objects, it will always appear over them if they overlap.

Hierarchy:

- **Main**

  - **Camera** (Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlBIy.png)
  - **BackgroundCanvas** (Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ODca.png)

    - **BackgroundImage** (Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6qGK.png)
  - **Object1** (Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38IzU.png)
  - **Object2**

Any advice to rescue me from this madness is much appreciated.

Comment: Your canvas is in Screenspace and therefore always on top of 3D objects. Have you tried to rather use a World space canvas?

Comment: I have tried World Space canvas, unfortunately it produces the same issue. (Both with an Event Camera attached, and not)

Comment: Is this correct: You have a 3D object that you want the canvas *in front* of, but the canvas is being hidden by the 3D object?  I'm not overly familiar with how sprite objects work, but try setting the sprite sorting layer to 'Default'

Comment: Not quite: I have two 2d objects (red squares in my gif, *Sprites*) in front of a canvas (green rectangle in my gif, *canvas Image*). The Canvas is in 'Default' Sorting Layer, and the Sprites are in a different sorting layer that is *in front of* Default. But, when an overlap occurs, the Canvas (which is definitely behind the sprites), appears in front of them. The game is 2d, but I made a gif showing it in 3d mode, simply to more easily show that the Canvas is for sure behind the sprites.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a workaround. I basically created a VisualElement inside the UI Builder and set a render texture to the background. Then I added an extra camera to my project to view all the sprites that needed to be on top. That camera feeds the render texture, so now everything that camera sees is forced to be on top of the UI Document as the background of that VisualElement. If you want control over the whole screen, just set the VisualElement position to absolute and max out its dimensions. If your game doesn't have a fixed aspect ratio it might cause some stretching, but other than that I cant really tell the difference. Sorting layers for the UI Documents are broken and unity needs to work on that. This is the best option I've found. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the sprite renderer's transform z value to 0 instead of 100

If that does not solve, please specify camera properties also, so I can try to recreate the exact setup.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Setting SpriteRenderers PosZ to 0 didn't seem to work. Here is the cameras inspector settings: https://i.imgur.com/Q5a52cf.png

Comment: now with the same setup as you shared, set back the sprite renderer's transform z to 100 and its set the order in layer to 1

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work :(

Comment: i tried to setup based the things you mentioned in your question, and the camera properties, for me this is the current output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DFWZ5MIh54GFm-YNNgfJCj28EvocCqX6/view?usp=sharing

Also you can directly have sprite renderer as background instead of canvas if you are not restricted with any other constraints.

But this seems minor miss on the setup side, else it should work, recently i have been working on projects with similar situations.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to set up your own example @hiren-katira. By doing so, I'm thinking you're right that it was probably one tiny minor issue somewhere in my mass of code that I just can't find. I did test with a simple sprite renderer, and that seems to work perfectly fine (appearing behind the sprites as I wanted), so I think I'll move forward with that method for now. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on `Layers -> edit layers`, inside sorting layers you can change the order grabbing layer, everything upper appears behind in the camera.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a layer called Object
Assign it to the game objects.
Create an object camera
culling mask -> object layer
depth bigger than you current main camera.
Set it to Projection -> Orthographic
Clear flags -> solid colors.
canvas Render Mode -> Screen Space - Camera and assign the Render Camera to be the Object Camera

Answer (score 0):

1. Inspector tab of the object or background.
2. Sprite Renderer.
3. Additional Settings.
4. Sorting Layer.
5. change it to a different layer.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and was able to fix it with these steps:

1. In canvas settings change Screen Space Overlay to Screen Space Camera
2. Set the camera variable to the one you are using for your scene.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it by changing the game objects into images instead - go to canvas and create new UI - image - and then attached the sprite that way... it worked for my context, but may not work with your set up :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by attaching the camera to the canvas which is screen space and finally changing the sorting layer of my object to -1.